# Disable pointer events on only the text in input field css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wish to disable pointer events on my input field, except on the text. This is because it is a read-only input field that you can copy from, but it showing pointer events on the empty part can be misleading and make people think its a read-write input field.
Is there a way to spesifically disable it everywhere but the text currently in the input field?

Comment: Have you tried `disabled` attribute? Would it work for your specific use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
input {
  pointer-events: none;
}
input[type="text"] {
  pointer-events: initial;
}
```

```html
text input:
<input value="some value" type="text">
<hr>
button input:
<input type="button">
<hr>
checkbox input:
<input type="checkbox">
<hr>
color input:
<input type="color">
<hr>
date input:
<input type="date">
<hr>
datetime-local input:
<input type="datetime-local">
<hr>
email input:
<input type="email">
<hr>
file input:
<input type="file">
<hr>
hidden input:
<input type="hidden">
<hr>
image input:
<input type="image">
<hr>
month input:
<input type="month">
<hr>
number input:
<input type="number">
<hr>
password input:
<input type="password">
<hr>
radio input:
<input type="radio">
<hr>
range input:
<input type="range">
<hr>
reset input:
<input type="reset">
<hr>
search input:
<input type="search">
<hr>
submit input:
<input type="submit">
<hr>
tel input:
<input type="tel">
<hr>
time input:
<input type="time">
<hr>
url input:
<input type="url">
<hr>
week input:
<input type="week">
```